# Can't alt+tab back into Starcraft

Tags: starcraft-2

I can alt tab to go out of the game, but when I want to go back in it doesn't want to be active, can I fix this with some kind of program?

(Its only on fullscreen programs that are acting like that).

Comment: found a fix, I just switched to windowed(fullscreen) now I can alt-tab.

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to settings, Graphisc and then Display mode=  Windowed(Fullscreen)

Comment: It's worth noting that 'Windowed (Fullscreen)' isn't supported in enough games, works fine for Blizzard games though.

Comment: Also works great in SW TOR

Comment: Can also be done is Valve games with some launch parameters.